Osada's Irreducibility Criterion
The criterion can be found for example as Theorem 2.2.7 in Prasolov's book Polynomials:

Theorem 2.2.7 ([Os1]). Let $f(x)=x^n+a_{1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}x\pm p$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, where $p$ is a prime.
$a)$ If $p>1+|a_{1}|+\cdots+|a_{n-1}|$, then $f$ is irreducible.
$b)$ If $p\ge 1+|a_{1}|+\cdots+|a_{n-1}|$ and among the roots of $f$ there are no roots
of unity, then $f$ is irreducible.

My question is in the proof of part $(b)$ why does it state that if $\alpha$ is not a root of unity then $|\alpha|\neq1$?
Proof.
Suppose that $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, where $g$ and $h$ are polynomials of positive degree with integer coefficients. The product of the constant terms of $g$ and $h$ is equal to $\pm p$. Since $p$ is prime, one of these constant terms is equal to $\pm 1$. Therefore, the product of the absolute values of the roots of one of the polynomials $g$ and $h$ is equal to $1$. This polynomial must therefore possess a root $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha| \leq 1$. Since $\alpha$ is also a root of $f$, it follows from $f(\alpha) = 0$ that
$$
p = |\alpha^n + a_1\alpha^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1}\alpha| \leq 1 + |a_1| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|.
$$
In case $(a)$, we arrive at a contradiction.
In case $(b)$, $\alpha$ is not a root of unity. Hence $|\alpha| < 1$, and therefore
$$
p < 1 + |a_1| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|.
$$
A contradiction again.
Any hint would be appreciated.

this should help: https://mathoverflow.net/q/10911.
